# how to make a pop-up window when click on some row

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have these lines in my code:

```
output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(df[df$country == "usa" ,]))
                  

output$ex2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(df[df$country == "france" ,]))
```

and now I want to make a pop-up window when I click on some row.
I found this code that looks useful:

```
observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected, {showModal(modalDialog(title = "You have selected a row!"))   })
```

but I'm not sure where I need to write this row in my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny datatable: popup data about selected row in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151436/shiny-datatable-popup-data-about-selected-row-in-a-new-window)

Comment: no, I saw this answer, but it didnt solve my problem. how I use it when i've output$ex1 and output$ex2?

Comment: Replace mydatatable by ex1 (or ex2) in the observeEvent so `observeEvent(input$mydatatable_row_selected ... ` -> `observeEvent(input$ex1_row_selected ... ` and  `mycars[input$mydatatable_rows_selected,] ` -> `df[df$country == "usa" ,][input$ex1_rows_selected,] `

Comment: ok, but where exactly I put this line?  output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(df[df$country == "usa" ,])), observeEvent(input$ex1_rows_selected, {showModal(modalDialog(title = "You have selected a row!"))   })

Answer (score 0):

The solution one proposes you in the comments works for row *selection*, and then it wouldn't work if you disable the selection.

Here is a solution for row *clicking*:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  splitLayout(
    DTOutput("dtable1"),
    DTOutput("dtable2")
  )
)

js <- function(id){ 
  c(
    "table.on('click', 'tr', function(){",
    sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s', true, {priority: 'event'});", id),
    "});"
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output[["dtable1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, callback = JS(js("t1")))
  })

  output[["dtable2"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, callback = JS(js("t2")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["t1"]], {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        "You clicked on a row of table 1"
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input[["t2"]], {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        "You clicked on a row of table 2"
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

If you want the index of the clicked row:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  splitLayout(
    DTOutput("dtable1"),
    DTOutput("dtable2")
  )
)

js <- function(id){ 
  c("console.log(table);",
    "table.on('click', 'tr', function(){",
    "  var index = this.rowIndex;",
    sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s', index, {priority: 'event'});", id),
    "});"
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output[["dtable1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, callback = JS(js("t1")))
  })

  output[["dtable2"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, callback = JS(js("t2")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["t1"]], {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        sprintf("You clicked on row number %d of table 1", input[["t1"]])
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input[["t2"]], {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        sprintf("You clicked on row number %d of table 2", input[["t2"]])
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: but I dont have 2 tables, i've just one table with a few bars